# Solr Querying TextField with PatternTokenizerFactory

Tags: solr, textfield, tokenize

I'm having trouble querying a TextField that is tokenized using PatternTokenizerFactory.

I'm using Solr version 4.7.2.

My Schema looks like:

```
<field name="filter_amenity_codes" type="caretDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" />
...
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="caretDelimited">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\^"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Field values looks like:
    "2^9^11^12^15^93"

Analysis on the field also looks good. It seems to tokenize the way I want it to.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiraY.png

So, now I'm trying to query this field to use as a filter. For example, I want to find all docs that contain the code 93. When i use the following query, I always get 0 docs in response. I have tried using the values 93, "93", /93/ and none of these return results.

The query i'm using looks like:
    filter_amenity_codes:93

This is what the response looks like:

```
{
    "response": {
        "docs": [],
        "numFound": 0,
        "start": 0
    },
    "responseHeader": {
        "QTime": 2,
        "params": {
            "_": "1407261941064",
            "indent": "true",
            "q": "filter_amenity_codes:93",
            "wt": "json"
        },
        "status": 0
    }
}
```

Is there something that I am not doing properly in the query? Or is my field in the schema not set up properly?

Comment: Do you have a document with "93" in it? your example shows 94.

Comment: oh oops, sorry, my mistake on the example.
yes, i have documents with 93 in them.

Comment: ok - can you add the actual query you are running?

Comment: for sure. I just updated my post above with the response. it has all the params in it.

Comment: do you have any spaces at the end of the field when indexing it?

Comment: no there are no spaces at the end

Comment: Do i need to specify an analyzer for both index and query? for example:
<analyzer type="index">
and
<analyzer type="query">

Comment: No that should be fine. can you share the code you are using to index and the sample document in raw form? You're schema looks okay but it's hard to know for sure without comparing it to the actual data being indexed.

Comment: the data is coming from a database and our mysql query does a group concat to generate the field data. For example: GROUP_CONCAT(FA.amenity_code_ppn SEPARATOR '^') filter_amenity_codes. This query generates strings like 1^6^7^8^12^13^14, 6^7^8^12, and 6^7^8^10^12^13. Is that what you meant?

Comment: and how are you getting the data into solr?

Comment: We use JdbcDataSource. Here is the skeleton of the data importer. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="********" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:mysql:************" user="****"/>
 <document>
  <entity name="****" query="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(FA.amenity_code_ppn SEPARATOR '^') filter_amenity_codes FROM db_name WHERE conditions"/>
 </document>
</dataConfig>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example schema works, as does querying - at least using Solr 4.9.0.

**data.json**

```
[
    {"id": 123, "filter_amenity_codes":"1^6^7^8^12^13^14"},
    {"id": 321, "filter_amenity_codes":"11^16^17^18^112^113^114"}
]
```

**schema.xml (extract)**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="filter_amenity_codes" type="caretDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="caretDelimited">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\^"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Data submitted to the index with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true --data-binary @data.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**Then queried**:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?
q=filter_amenity_codes:12&wt=json&indent=true
```

**Results in**:

```
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "id":"123",
    "filter_amenity_codes":"1^6^7^8^12^13^14",
    "_version_":1475631637529100288}]
  }]}
```

If you're unable to get the same output, your import process is probably failing. Do a query for `*:*` to see that you've actually indexed any values, try submitting the JSON file instead to see if that is searchable (which means your import is failing), and be sure to set up SolrLogging properly so that any errors gets logged. If your query from the comments is anywhere close to correct, you're missing both GROUP BY and any table named FA etc, so I can't say anything about that.